# Renaming variables in FriCAS sandbox output

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I'm playing with FriCAS in [sandbox](http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl/FriCASIntegration#bottom) and the problem is,
When asked to find indefinite integral (as well as in many other cases), FriCAS outputs auto-generated variables in a rather unsightly manner, for example,

```
integrate(x^x, x)
```

outputs $\int_{}^x\%A^{\%A}\mathbb{d}\%A$ which is quite ugly.

The question is, is there a way to prettify the output? How can I substitute $\%A$ with $t$, for example?

Comment: You could ask e.g. at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fricas-devel .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I contacted the guys at the fricas google group, as IV_ suggested in his comment to the question. Thanks again for pointing me there!

Waldek Hebisch [posted the following code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fricas-devel/OcAocpXmC-k) that solves my problem:

```
)expose OutputFormTools

subst_of(f, ls, lf) ==
    symbol?(f) =>
        s := symbol(f)
        k := position(s, ls)
        k > 0 => lf(k)
        f
    atom?(f) => f
    la := arguments(f)
    nla := [subst_of(fi, ls, lf) for fi in la]
    construct(operator(f), nla)$OutputFormTools
```

It would perform the necessary dummy variable substitution when used like this:

```
iif := integrate(x^x, x)::OutputForm;
subst_of(iif, [%A], [t])
```

Which will produce a much cleaner answer, $\int_{}^{x}t^t\mathbb{d}t$, and that was precisely what I was looking for.